# Google+ SignInButton class cannot be instantiated in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, google-plus

Am trying to add the Google+ sign in button to my app but when i place the code

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

in my `fragment-main.xml` file, i get this error

```
  Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
  - com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
  Exception Details android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not
  find        
  drawable resource matching value 0x7FFF0014 (resolved name:   

  common_signin_btn_text_dark) in current configuration. at 
  android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)  at   
  android.content.res.BridgeResources.getColorStateList(BridgeResources.java:204)
  at   com.google.android.gms.internal.do.c  at  
  com.google.android.gms.internal.do.a  at  
  com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.c  at 
  com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.p  at 
  com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setStyle  at 
  com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>  at
  com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>  at 
  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)   at 
  android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)   at 
  android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64) at
  android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at 
  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

The `SignInButton` class does exist in the `package com.google.android.gms.common;`
     package.How do i get past this please?

Comment: Can you please post your error as text and not an image?

Comment: how are you importing the Google Play Services?

Comment: through 

`dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
 }`

Comment: This question has been marked as duplicate, but the "answer" i am being directed to focuses on IntelliJ